# Turn off default debugging output at the site level - Coldfusion 10

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfadmin

This might be a bug or corrupt file issue, but for some reason, I'm seeing the debugging output at the bottom of one of my CF10 websites. I can go in and add `<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">` and it turns off, but on my other websites, it's off by default. On those sites, I have to add `<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">` for the debugging to show up.

I checked the CF Administrator and for this site and another that's behaving correctly, but I'm not seeing any differences.  I don't have any IPs added to the **Debugging IP Addresses**, so that's not it either.

I can go into **Debugger Settings** and turn off **Enable Request Debugging Output** to get it to disappear, but then even `<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">` doesn't turn it on when I want it. Plus I didn't have to do that on other sites that are working correctly.

Thoughts?

Comment: A) you _should_ put an IP in the list of IP addresses (127.0.0.1) otherwise when turned ON everyone will see everything (a security risk). B) I would do a string search for cfsetting in your code and see if there is one somewhere you missed. Or possibly an application.cfc or cfm that's lurking and being run.

Comment: look for onRequestend.cfm or check out the onrequestend() function as well...

Comment: Thanks @Mark A Kruger.  The tip that I should add 127.0.0.1 to my list of IP addresses was the answer. I never knew that it was required to avoid it showing to all IPs, but I guess that makes sense in a way. Add your answer as an answer, and I'll pick it.

Comment: Done - thanks Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that when there is *no* ip address in the allowed IP addresses, debugging is shown to everyone willy nilly. Make sure and keep/add 127.0.0.1 then only *that* IP is allowed. Subsequently you can add other IPs as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check your Application.cfc as well for the following:

```
this.debuggingIPAddresses
```

Comment: Good tip. That wasn't it in my case, but it's a valid thing to check.